# Python matplotlib annotate variable length arc

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

I would like to annotate some points in a matplotlib plot (dynamically ofc) with "arc" connectionstyles in such a way that the annotations are grouped at the top, the connectors running to their respective x-positions, but stop at a defined y-position, and extend as straight arms from their to the data point (see fig). The solution might be manipulating the individual "armB"-values, but the problem there is that those are only in points and don't correspond to the data coordinate system. The reason I don't just use straight lines in the first place is that in the real data, the points are sometimes too close together and the text would overlap, hence the bent "arrows". Oh, and it should dynamically adapt to the zoom level (the final plot being interactive), but I think I'll be able to pull that off once the connection line problem is solved. Minimal working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11]
y=[1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2,]
tx=[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
yd=dict(zip(x, y))

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.xlim(0, 14)
plt.ylim(0, 7)

arpr = {"arrowstyle": "-", "connectionstyle": "arc,angleA=-90,armA=20,angleB=90,armB=20,rad=10"}
for i, j in zip(x, tx):
    #lines all the way down but messy
    plt.annotate("foo", (i, yd[i]), (j, 6), arrowprops=arpr, rotation="vertical")
    #lines orderly, but incomplete
    plt.annotate("foo", (i, 5), (j, 6), arrowprops=arpr, rotation="vertical")
```

What I would like (red lines are the issue, added in the pic w/ MS paint...):
[image]

Just clipping the connectors to the data points, not good:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the length of `armB` so that it's dependent on the position of the point.

Here's an example for what I thought looked good:

[image]

```
connection = "arc,angleA=-90,armA=20,angleB=90,rad=10,"
arpr = {"arrowstyle": "-"}

for i, j in zip(x, tx):
    #lines all the way down but messy
    arpr["connectionstyle"] = connection + "armB="+ "{0}".format((5-yd[i])*30)
    plt.annotate("foo", (i, yd[i]), (j, 6), arrowprops=arpr, rotation="vertical")
```

Comment: Note that the lengths of the arrows are defined in "display space". So they get deformed when you resize the plot, or when you add points that make the y limits change. This makes that the solution only works well for a fixed size plot (what might be enough for OP's use case).